How to solve "'arg' must be NULL or a character vector" error in ode function of deSolve package
I am trying to create an epidemiological SEIR model and simulate the model compartments over time. More specifically, the code below code defines a function called Metapopulation_SEIR. This function represents a compartmental model known as the Metapopulation SEIR model, which is commonly used in epidemiology to simulate the spread of infectious diseases in multiple interconnected populations.See the code:
library(deSolve)
library(ggplot2)

# Metapopulation SEIR model function
Metapopulation_SEIR <- function(time, current_state, params, connectivity_matrix){
  with(as.list(c(current_state, params)),{
    # Calculate total population size in each subpopulation
    N <- apply(current_state, 1, sum)
    
    # Initialize rate of change vectors
    dS <- rep(0, nrow(current_state))
    dE <- rep(0, nrow(current_state))
    dI <- rep(0, nrow(current_state))
    dR <- rep(0, nrow(current_state))
    dM <- rep(0, nrow(current_state))
    
    # Loop through each subpopulation
    for (i in 1:nrow(current_state)) {
      # Calculate total number of individuals in subpopulation i
      Ni <- N[i]
      
      # Calculate rates of change for each compartment in subpopulation i
      dSi <- -beta * S[i] * I[i] / Ni
      dEi <- (beta * S[i] * I[i] / Ni) - sigma * E[i]
      dIi <- sigma * E[i] - gamma * I[i] - mu * I[i]
      dRi <- gamma * I[i]
      dMi <- mu * I[i]
      
      # Update rate of change vectors
      dS[i] <- dSi
      dE[i] <- dEi
      dI[i] <- dIi
      dR[i] <- dRi
      dM[i] <- dMi
      
      # Calculate movement of individuals between subpopulations
      for (j in 1:nrow(current_state)) {
        dS[i] <- dS[i] + connectivity_matrix[i, j] * (beta * S[j] * I[j] / Ni)
        dE[i] <- dE[i] + connectivity_matrix[i, j] * (sigma * E[j])
        dI[i] <- dI[i] + connectivity_matrix[i, j] * (gamma * I[j])
        dR[i] <- dR[i] + connectivity_matrix[i, j] * (gamma * R[j])
        dM[i] <- dM[i] + connectivity_matrix[i, j] * (mu * I[j])
      }
    }
    
    # Return a list of rates of change for each compartment
    return(list(c(dS, dE, dI, dR, dM)))
  })
}

# Example inputs
# Number of subpopulations
num_subpopulations <- 3

# Initial compartment counts for each subpopulation
initial_state <- matrix(c(
  S1 = 900, E1 = 10, I1 = 5, R1 = 85,
  S2 = 950, E2 = 5,  I2 = 2, R2 = 43,
  S3 = 850, E3 = 15, I3 = 7, R3 = 100
), ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE)

# Parameters
params <- c(beta = 0.5, sigma = 0.25, gamma = 0.2, mu = 0.001)

# Connectivity matrix (specifies the movement of individuals between subpopulations)
# Example: Fully connected network where individuals can move between all subpopulations
connectivity_matrix <- matrix(0.1, nrow = num_subpopulations, ncol = num_subpopulations)
diag(connectivity_matrix) <- 1  # Individuals stay within their own subpopulation

# Time points
times <- seq(0, 365, by = 1)

# Solve the model
model <- ode(initial_state, times, Metapopulation_SEIR, params, connectivity_matrix)

Which give the following error in the last line:

Error in match.arg(method) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector

I tried to name the argument as follows:
model <- ode(initial_state, times, Metapopulation_SEIR, parms=params, connectivity_matrix)

But still getting the same error.

If you look at the documentation for deSolve::ode it expects five named arguments and then .... Your unnamed arguments will be matched, in order, with the five arguments that the function expects, but any others you specify (as part of the ...) will need to be explicitly named in your call. In particular, the fifth argument of ode is "method", which should be a character string, whereas it looks as if you are passing it a matrix, so I'm guessing that ought to be one of the ... arguments.

Thank you for your help. Should I explicitly name the method argument to avoid this?

You can either name it or put it fifth, but it needs to be a character string, not a matrix. See ?deSolve::ode for the available options.

Another problem is, that initial_state needs to be reformatted as matrix before passing it to the solver. It can be reformatted as matrix internally in the model function and then returned again as vector.

The code contained several mistakes:

extra names in the ode call must be named
initial_state must be passed as matrix
names of a matrix cannot easily be unpacked with with
number of initial states must be equal to the number of derivatives

A further issue is, that it is not necessary to use loops. R is a vectorized language, so that states can directly be formulated in matrix form, which makes the code more compact and much faster.
Below an intermediate version of the code, solving only the errors, but still contains loops.
However, I would also strongly recommend to re-formulate the model in matrix form. An example can be found here: https://github.com/tpetzoldt/covid/blob/master/models/sir_metapopulation.R
This code contains essentially two versions of the state equations, one outcommented version with separate equations and one that uses matrix multiplication.
library(deSolve)

# Metapopulation SEIR model function
Metapopulation_SEIR <- function(time, current_state, params, connectivity_matrix, n_sub){
  # tp: access to names in state **matrix** not possible with "with",
  #     this works only for vectors like 'parms'
  #with(as.list(c(current_state, params)),{
  with(as.list(params),{ 
    
    # tp: reformat state vector as matrix
    dim(current_state) <- c(n_sub, 5)
    
    # tp: extract states
    S <- current_state[,1]
    E <- current_state[,2]
    I <- current_state[,3]
    R <- current_state[,4]
    M <- current_state[,5]
    
    # Calculate total population size in each subpopulation
    N <- apply(current_state, 1, sum)
    
    # Initialize rate of change vectors
    dS <- rep(0, nrow(current_state))
    dE <- rep(0, nrow(current_state))
    dI <- rep(0, nrow(current_state))
    dR <- rep(0, nrow(current_state))
    dM <- rep(0, nrow(current_state))
    
    # tp: loop is not necessary, R is a vectorized language
    # Loop through each subpopulation
    for (i in 1:nrow(current_state)) {
      # Calculate total number of individuals in subpopulation i
      Ni <- N[i]
      
      # Calculate rates of change for each compartment in subpopulation i
      dSi <- -beta * S[i] * I[i] / Ni
      dEi <- (beta * S[i] * I[i] / Ni) - sigma * E[i]
      dIi <- sigma * E[i] - gamma * I[i] - mu * I[i]
      dRi <- gamma * I[i]
      dMi <- mu * I[i]
      
      # Update rate of change vectors
      dS[i] <- dSi
      dE[i] <- dEi
      dI[i] <- dIi
      dR[i] <- dRi
      dM[i] <- dMi
      
      # Calculate movement of individuals between subpopulations
      for (j in 1:nrow(current_state)) {
        dS[i] <- dS[i] + connectivity_matrix[i, j] * (beta * S[j] * I[j] / Ni)
        dE[i] <- dE[i] + connectivity_matrix[i, j] * (sigma * E[j])
        dI[i] <- dI[i] + connectivity_matrix[i, j] * (gamma * I[j])
        dR[i] <- dR[i] + connectivity_matrix[i, j] * (gamma * R[j])
        dM[i] <- dM[i] + connectivity_matrix[i, j] * (mu * I[j])
      }
    }
    
    # Return a list of rates of change for each compartment
    return(list(c(dS, dE, dI, dR, dM)))
  })
}

# Example inputs
# Number of subpopulations
num_subpopulations <- 3

# Initial compartment counts for each subpopulation
# tp: add 5th column for M states
initial_state <- matrix(c(
  S1 = 900, E1 = 10, I1 = 5, R1 = 85, M1=0,
  S2 = 950, E2 = 5,  I2 = 2, R2 = 43, M2=0,
  S3 = 850, E3 = 15, I3 = 7, R3 = 100, M3=0
), ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE)

# tp: reformat initial_state into vector
initial_state <- as.vector(initial_state)


# Parameters
params <- c(beta = 0.5, sigma = 0.25, gamma = 0.2, mu = 0.001)

# Connectivity matrix (specifies the movement of individuals between subpopulations)
# Example: Fully connected network where individuals can move between all subpopulations
connectivity_matrix <- matrix(0.1, nrow = num_subpopulations, ncol = num_subpopulations)
diag(connectivity_matrix) <- 1  # Individuals stay within their own subpopulation

# Time points
times <- seq(0, 365, by = 1)

# Solve the model

# tp: add n_sub argument
model <- ode(initial_state, times, Metapopulation_SEIR, params, "lsoda", 
             connectivity_matrix = connectivity_matrix, n_sub=num_subpopulations)


# tp: alternative: works too, but extra arguments must always be named
model <- ode(initial_state, times, Metapopulation_SEIR, params, 
             connectivity_matrix = connectivity_matrix, n_sub=num_subpopulations)


Just a short comment: the equations above still produce implausible results. I would guess, that this is because of a wrong formulation of the connectivity-loop that should contain only transport and no reaction terms.

You may consider to post a final solution here. This would be a valuable contribution to the knowledge base.
